# Belvedere exe. keeps disappearing

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7 32bit. I keep installing Belvedere, but the exe file keeps disappearing. I have cleared every mention in the register and on the main disk but this continues. This is the only executable that behaves this way.
Any suggestions? Or any suggestion for a good alternative?

Answer (score 2):

`Belvedere.exe` can be falsely reported as a trojan by some antiviruses. Your AV is deleting it every time you try to install it.
To solve your problem, you can deactivate your AV during the installation, and then add the program in its whitelist (or ignored files).

Comment: It does NOT get deleted on install but when I shut down and then reboot either then or in the morning it is gone.  I have tried to protect it in the Microft Security Essentials and Super Antispyware.  I will check to see if there are any other culprits lurking.  Thanks.